# nodejs native addon multithreading

Tags: c++, node.js, multithreading, v8, node.js-addon

I have developed native modules for nodejs during a little period of time and some cases aren't quite clear for me. Unfortunately v8 documentation isn't very good.

So there are one of the interesting field for me. 
First of all is it possible to use `std::thread` in main native module thread? Documentation say that I can use libuv functions and run async operations, but inside this library we haven't access to v8 objects. But what if I want to parallel my computations synchronous in main thread and, for example, modify some JS object properties with its result in another thread?

I tried following code:

```
double result;
void myFunction(Local<Value> a, Local<Value> b)
{
    std::cout << "from thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " " << std::endl;
    result = a->NumberValue() + b->NumberValue();
}
void add(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
  std::cout << "main "<< std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
  thread thread(myFunction, args[0], args[1]);
  thread.join();
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(Number::New(isolate, result));
}
```

And it works as I expect, but why if we haven't access to v8 objects in another thread ?

I also tried change result to v8::Number type and create it inside myFunction via current isolate and new isolate, but get seg fault.

Comment: Do you use mutexes for changing global objects? Usually segfault causes in this case. There is a good addon for catching segfaults https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler and this is a library, which also uses std::threads https://github.com/yarax/nnb

Comment: @RaxWunter I agree with architecture of the second example, when in main JS event loop we extract data, fill via them C++ structures, run async function and execute with any thread numbers in another event loop. Ok, but I thought, what if coping and forming c++ structures is not light-weight operation, is it possible to operate JS objects in main JS event loop by running from this N threads (not another event loop, just threads). And I found that using libuv it isn't (as mentioned in doc), but using, for example c++11 threads I can forward Local<Number> reference into thread and this works.

Answer (score 0):

@RaxWunter in other words I don't understand why such code works

```
void myFunction(Local<Value> a, Local<Value> b, Isolate* pIsolate, Local<Number>& num)
{
    cout << "from thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " " << pIsolate << endl; 
    num = Number::New(pIsolate, a->NumberValue() + b->NumberValue()); 
} 
void add(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args)
{ 
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate(); 
    Local<Number> num; 
    thread thread1(myFunction, args[0], args[1], isolate, std::ref(num));
    thread1.join(); 
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(num); 
}
void Init(Local<Object> exports) 
{
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "add", add);
}
NODE_MODULE(addon, Init)
```